# SQL Server: Error message on dynamic procecure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dynamic

I don't have much experience with dynamic procedures so the following was only an attempt. 
The only part that is actually dynamic here is the table name which I tried to create by combining the fix part "`MOC_`" and the variable part `@level`.

Can someone tell me what I have to change here to make this work ?

The error I get when executing this points to the `IF NOT EXISTS` part:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'IF NOT EXISTS (
>                           SELECT  * 
>                           FROM    MOC_Nav2
>                           WHERE   itemID = ' to data type int.

My procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MOC_UpdateNav]
    @level nvarchar(20),
    @itemID int,
    @parentID int,
    @itemName nvarchar(100),
    @sortID int,
    @logStatus nvarchar(20),
    @lastUpdate nvarchar(50),
    @modBy varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    BEGIN   

    DECLARE     @sql nvarchar(max)

    SET @sql = 'IF NOT EXISTS 
                (
                        SELECT  * 
                        FROM    MOC_' + @level + '
                        WHERE   itemID = ' + @itemID + '
                )
                INSERT INTO MOC_' + @level + '
                (
                        parentID,
                        itemName,
                        sortID,
                        logStatus,
                        lastUpdate,
                        modDate,
                        modBy
                )
                SELECT  ' + @parentID + ',
                        ' + @itemName + ',
                        ' + @sortID + ',
                        ' + @logStatus + ',
                        ' + @lastUpdate + ',
                        GETDATE(),
                        ' + @modBy + '
                ELSE
                        UPDATE  MOC_' + @level + '
                        SET     parentID = ' + @parentID + ',
                                itemName = ' + @itemName + ',
                                sortID = ' + @sortID + ',
                                logStatus = ' + @logStatus + ',
                                lastUpdate = ' + @lastUpdate + ',
                                modDate = GETDATE(),
                                modBy = ' + @modBy + '
                        WHERE   itemID = ' + @itemID + ''

    EXEC(@sql)

    END
END
```

Comment: Oh my, the SQL injection, it burns... [Please use `sp_executesql`](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp-executesql.aspx) and parameterize every single variable there except the only one you can't, `@level`, and use `QUOTENAME('MOC_' + @level)`.

Comment: You might want to read up on SQL injection ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), [here](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/sql-injection-vulnerability-history/) and [here](http://www.troyhunt.com/2013/07/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-sql.html)) before waving sound advice away as useless. It's kind of how most security exploits you hear about on the news happen. Do you want to be on the news?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@itemID` is an `int`. Because it is used in the expression, everything else [must be converted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) to a number, including your SQL text.

Convert `@itemID` [(and other numbers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25340287/sql-server-error-message-on-dynamic-procecure#comment39507047_25340309) to nvarchar before concatenating it into the query:

```
SET @sql = N'IF NOT EXISTS 
    (
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    MOC_' + @level + '
        WHERE   itemID = ' + cast(@itemID as nvarchar(30)) + ...
```

Comment: `@sortID` and `@parentID` too.

Comment: @GSerg: Thanks a lot for this ! I will accept as soon as I can.

Comment: Also [don't convert to `nvarchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I never declare varchars without lenghts and I slap people who do, but for some reason I feel attracted to the fact the lenght is 30 by default when converting numerics.

Comment: @GSerg bad habit to promote, because not everyone who reads your code knows that, or that in some cases (even when converting numerics) it's **1**, not **30**. Do what you want in your own code, but I think if you're trying to teach people that's the wrong kind of thing to pass on.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am concerned now; in which case will the lenght be 1 when converting numerics?

Comment: @GSerg two examples are input parameters and variable declarations. You could consider [reading the post I linked earlier](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx?maybe).

Comment: @AaronBertrand I have read that post, but there is nothing about converting numerics, only about declaring variables/columns without length. That is bad and I never do that, but you said the length might be 1 "even when converting numerics," which was what I was concerned about. Did you mean "even when converting numerics, provided that you immediately store the result into an improperly declared variable"?

Comment: And also, of course, consider that you need to change your approach if you are converting `NUMERIC(38,10)`. So, once again, I see *absolutely* no benefit to not declaring length in *all* scenarios, and only see danger in leaving it out and therefore implying to less experienced users that this is always going to be okay. This is like saying it's ok to go 140mph on the day you think the local cop is on the other side of town.

Comment: Well, yes, you mean "provided that you immediately store the result into an improperly declared variable." This really has nothing to do with using `cast()` and `convert()`. One can achieve the same result by doing `declare @v varchar = cast(42 as varchar(30))` - that will not be the fault of the code inside the `cast()`. Point taken about numeric(38,10) however.

Comment: It's about *consistency* and not forcing newbies to learn all the rules about when it's okay to be lazy (if you consider saving four whole keystrokes lazy) and when it will bite them in the ass. Or not learn the rules at all until it has bitten them in the ass - I've seen people who have lost data, permanently, because they had input parameters without length definitions, and all their strings were truncated to 1 for several hours before they noticed.